# Apache configuration broken after software update

Tags: php, apache, configuration, indexing, url-rewriting

I just updated my Ubuntu outdated development server, and it broke down some configuration.
Now apache/php does not properly handle urls like `index.php/profile`, but will handle correctly just `index.php`.

Basically if there some path after `index.php`, then it will return 404 error:
The requested URL /index.php/profile was not found on this server.

What configuration option is likely to fix this problem? I need to fix this urgently. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the setting of [AcceptPathInfo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo):

> This directive controls whether requests that contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. The trailing pathname information can be made available to scripts in the PATH_INFO environment variable.
>
> For example, assume the location /test/ points to a directory that contains only the single file here.html. Then requests for /test/here.html/more and /test/nothere.html/more both collect /more as PATH_INFO.